# search through array of records

Tags: php, symfony

I have OneToMany relation between Category and Sections. What i'm trying to do is implement editing for sections. So my edit action so far looks like this:

```
/**
   *
   *
   * @Route("category/{category_id}/section/{id}/edit", name="section_edit")
   * @Method("GET")
   * @Template()
   */



public function editAction($category_id, $id)

  {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $category = $em->getRepository('MyOwnBundle:Category')->find($category_id);

  if (!$category) {
      throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Category entity.');
  }

    ////.....
```

}

all pretty straightforward, but i don't really know how to browse sections that belongs to $category. To perform editing i need this one specific record, which has id == $id. Obviously i cant simply look through ALL the sections because then i wouldnt know whether what i find really belongs to $category. Any simple methods that will allow me to do this, or should i simple loop through this `$category->getSections()` one by one?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple.

You can rely on `ParamConverter` to load necesarry objects. **It will fail if any of those were not found**

You can read more about it [**here**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html). Don't forget to import (`use`) ParamConverter annotation!

```
/**
* @Route("category/{category_id}/section/{id}/edit", name="section_edit")
* @ParamConverter("category", class="AcmeBundle:Category", options={"id": "category_id"})
* @Method("GET")
* @Template()
*/
public function editAction(Category $category, Section $section){
    // both category and section are fully loaded, no need to go to doctrine or check if they are null

    if ( !$section->getCategories()->contains($category)){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Invalid request.');
    }

    ...
    the rest of your logic
    ...
}
```